# Remove GitHub icon from VSCode statusbar

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I hide the "Publish to GitHub" cloud [icon](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-status-bar-actions):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to install the [Custom CSS and JS Loader extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css), you can follow the installation instructions as normal.

When setting the `vscode_custom_css.imports` key in `settings.json` as part of those instructions, you can add a reference to the [small custom stylesheet I've published to GitHub](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/esqew/911ad7d537d8b356d5715b6310d872dc/raw/fc6ce07e1f3fec86b42dc82967e98170d39fce53/style.css), which will hide the cloud icon when it would otherwise be presented in the interface:

[image]

---

If installing a new extension is a non-starter, you can right-click on the status bar and select the "Source Control" option, which will remove the cloud icon, but also all other source control-related items (including the branch name) as well. Unfortunately, there isn't a more granular way out-of-the-box to target this icon specifically.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of that extension, but prefer not to hack vscode itself. I was hoping there were some way to disable that icon specifically (I have so many junk icons in the taskbar!) but I guess the answer is "it cannot be done". Thanks for the alternative, I'm sure it's an option for other users.

Answer (score 0):

There is a release note including an option to hide the "Sync changes" button in the version control tab. Maybe this setting hides the icon in the status bar too?

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61#_publish-or-sync-action-button-for-git-repositories

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

just press `Hide 'Source Control Publish'`
[image: image description]